# How to highlight text without losing the text case using javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, text, filtering, highlight

I'm developing a HTML list filter using JQuery to do the job.
The objective is to hide the items witch text doesn't match with the text inserted on the input.

HTML:

```
<div class="search-form">
  <form method="post">
    <input id="sntndr-search-txt" type="text" class="search-txt" placeholder="Filter..." data-search-id="accounts-filter">
  </form>
</div>                      
<ul class="accounts-list" data-search-list="accounts-filter">
  <li data-account-id="9432657645">
    <a href="#" class="account">
      <div class="title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="description">004900029089 232</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-account-id="35532436">
    <a href="#" class="account">
      <div class="title">Special account</div>
      <div class="description">543634523445 232</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    //Data search
    $('*[data-search-id]').on('keyup', function(event ) {
        var listToBeSearched = $('*[data-search-list='+$(this).attr('data-search-id')+']');
        var self = this;

        //Hide all items
        $('li', listToBeSearched).hide();
        $(listToBeSearched.find('li')).each(function(index, item) {

            //Reset highlight
            var highlightedText = $('b.highlight', item).eq(0).text();
            $(item).html(function() {
                return $(this).html().replace(new RegExp( '<b class="highlight">'+highlightedText+'</b>' , 'gi'), highlightedText);
            })

            //Set highlight
            $(':not(:has(*))', item).html(function() {
                return $(this).html().replace(new RegExp( "(" + $(self).val() + ")" , 'gi'), '<b class="highlight">'+$(self).val()+'</b>');
            });

            //Show the matched items
            var currentItemText = $(item).text();
            if(currentItemText.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf($(self).val().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                $(item).show();
            }
        })

        return false;
    });
});
```

The problem is when i try to highlight the text on the list items, and i lose the text case. For example, i am searching for "lorem" and where i had "Lorem", now i have "lorem". I know where the problem is. This happens because i replace the entire text on the list items.

Is there a better way to do that without losing the original text case?

You can test the code here:
JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vmwj5w4L/

Comment: Does this need to take into account any possible uppercase, or just the first character of each word?

Comment: Any possible uppercase

Comment: **You don't need to reinvert the wheel**, just use an existing component like [mark.js](https://markjs.io/). For your use case have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/bs69vcqL/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

In your `//Set highlight` code, you're replacing the found text with `$(self).val()`...

```
return $(this).html().replace(
    new RegExp( "(" + $(self).val() + ")" , 'gi'),
    '<b class="highlight">'+$(self).val()+'</b>'
);
```

...when you could simply replace it with a backreference to exactly the found text, `$1`, like this:

```
return $(this).html().replace(
    new RegExp( "(" + $(self).val() + ")" , 'gi'),
    '<b class="highlight">$1</b>'
);
```

You also need to fix your `//Reset highlight` code, similarly, taking this...

```
return $(this).html().replace(
    new RegExp( '<b class="highlight">'+highlightedText+'</b>' , 'gi'),
    highlightedText
);
```

and adding a capturing group `()` and again referring to the backreference `$1`:

```
return $(this).html().replace(
    new RegExp( '<b class="highlight">('+highlightedText+')</b>' , 'gi'),
    '$1'
);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vmwj5w4L/6/. Happy coding!

Comment: Great!! but can you take a look here? https://jsfiddle.net/vmwj5w4L/5/
Try to type "special" on the input. You can figure that all other "s" on the item go uppercase.

Comment: See my update. You need to fix `//Reset highlight` accordingly.

Comment: Just so you know, there are some improvements possible, if you find performance lagging as you use larger lists. For example, to "reset," why not just do `$('.accounts-list').hide()`, and have a separate `ul` classed `accounts-list-filtered` into which you `append()` `copy()`ed `li`s from the original list, and do the RegExp replacement there. Because then, all you have to do to reset is `$('.accounts-list-filtered').remove()` to destroy that list, and `$('.accounts-list').show()` to reshow your original list, instead of doing all those RegExps again, which is slow and error-prone.

Comment: You just saved my day! Thanks :)